# Render link only if props data contains a particular value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to link employe names to CVs on an `About` page. However, some people do not have a CV. I want to remove the `a` tag/the link on the name if they do not have CV PDFs filled out in my JSON file. I know how to do this outside of React, I'm just unsure when the javascript needs to be in the render rather than return area, as I have my information set up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';
import '../styles/PersonCard.css';


class PersonCard extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-container">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="side">
            <Image 
              className="card-img-top"
              src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/bios/" + this.props.data.img_name}
              height={249}
              width={249} 
            />
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/pdfs/" + this.props.data.pdf}>
              <h5 className="card-title">
                {this.props.data.name + " " + this.props.data.credentials}
              </h5>
            </a>
            <h6 className="card-text">{this.props.data.position}</h6>
            <p className="card-text">{this.props.data.email}</p>
            <p className="card-text">{this.props.data.phone}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonCard;
```

P.S. The JSON is set up in this format:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "credentials": "PhD",
    "position": "Professor",
    "email": "jsmith@uni.edu",
    "phone": "123-456-7890",
    "designations": [
        "Faculty"
    ],
    "img_name": "JohnSmith.jpg",
    "pdf": "jSmithCV.pdf"

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced conditional component rendering in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504012/advanced-conditional-component-rendering-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion would be to create an extra component which will render its children:

```
const CVComponent = ({ children, pdf }) => pdf ? (
  <a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/pdfs/" + pdf}>
    {children}
  </a>
) : <div>{children}</div>;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
class PersonCard extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-container">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="side">
            <Image 
              className="card-img-top"
              src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/bios/" + this.props.data.img_name}
              height={249}
              width={249} 
            />
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <CVComponent pdf={this.props.data.pdf}>
              <h5 className="card-title">
                {this.props.data.name + " " + this.props.data.credentials}
              </h5>
            </CVComponent>
            <h6 className="card-text">{this.props.data.position}</h6>
            <p className="card-text">{this.props.data.email}</p>
            <p className="card-text">{this.props.data.phone}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```